# Getting a "list index is out of range" for a simple list split

Tags: python, line, readlines

I am trying to read lines from a txt document into a list, but I keep getting the message: **IndexError: list index out of range**. It points to the last line **password = usersdoc[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZFCc.jpg).strip()** as the problem.

```
k = open(filename, 'r')

lines = k.readlines()

for line in lines:

    
    usersdoc=line.strip().split('-')

    username = usersdoc[0].strip()

    password = usersdoc[1].strip()
```

The document I am reading has a username and a password on each line separated by '-' and I am able to print **username** and **password** successfully, but when I run my full code I just get an error. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. [Here is the document I am reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZFCc.jpg)

Comment: Line 2 has a username, i.e., "Jack", but no password. So, `usersdoc[1]` is what is causing the error, b/c there is not second element in that line.

Comment: Thank you! I added  

if len(usersdoc) <= 1:
            continue

and that seemed to fix

Comment: The answer below's already got you covered, but you might also be interested in [multiple assignment](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/). It can be nice and clean to write, for instance, `username, password = line.strip().split(' - ')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `for` loop reaches the line:

```
Jack
```

the function split('-') only returns a list with a single value: "Jack" Said list doesn't have an index of [1] because it only has one value, which is index [0].

To bypass this, you can do a couple things depending on how you want to handle it:

Ignore the line entirely:

```py
for line in lines:
    usersdoc=line.strip().split('-')
    if len(usersdoc) !== 2:
        continue
    username = usersdoc[0].strip()
    password = usersdoc[1].strip()
```

Create an empty password:

```py
for line in lines:
    usersdoc=line.strip().split('-')
    username = usersdoc[0].strip()
    password = usersdoc[1].strip() if usersdoc[1] else ""
```

Something I noticed that you may not have caught yet, because `strip()` comes before `split()`, your usernames and passwords can still have whitespace on either side if there's whitespace between the username/password and the dash.

Comment: Thank you! It might be painfully obvious that this is from an Intro to Python class, and I am very much "Intro". I appreciate the help!